# Invalid symlink in node_modules error when trying to deploy to simulator (RN 0.45)

Tags: android, react-native, xcode8

After making an upgrade from 0.39.2 t 0.45.1 and updating node packages and fixing about 50 issues in xcode my build succeeds but when trying to deploy on simulator I get.

> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app
> An error was encountered processing the command
> (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=70):
>
> **invalid symlink** at
> /Users/dob99/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9BEB7AD7-F8CD-4CF9-BEA5-B995D2CE07E9/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.6ItzQQ/extracted/AppName/**node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver**
> Launching  An error was encountered processing the
> command (domain=NSMachErrorDomain, code=-308): The operation couldn’t
> be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.45.1

xCode: 8.3.3

Please advice.

***Note:** I was able to reproduce this later on building for android too. The fix with the `unlink` command from below fixed the android issue too.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My team was getting the same error yesterday.  This apparently fixed it for them:

`unlink node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver`

Here's more info about the bug:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14417

Comment: How can unlink, even test-driver does not exit ?.

Comment: @LeangSocheat Did you find a solution cause I am in the same case