# Could not list contents of 'third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver'. Couldn't follow symbolic link

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a project build on react-native version `0.55.4`. It was woking fine on old system. I have to change system due to some reasons. I setup on new system, I am able to run project using react-native run-android but when building a signed APK using ./gradlew assembleRelease I am receiving following error.

```
Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file:
<Project-Directory>/android/app/google-services.json

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Could not list contents of

'<Project-Directory>/node_modules/react-native/scripts/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

I know this issue is already on stack overflow [Invalid symlink in node_modules error when trying to deploy to simulator (RN 0.45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847537/invalid-symlink-in-node-modules-error-when-trying-to-deploy-to-simulator-rn-0-4). I have tried it. I have also tried following github question.

1. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11212
2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14417
3. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14548
4. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14464

I have also tried following things.

1. Deleting node modules and reinstalling them
2. Deleting `.bin` folder in node modules
3. Deleting `react-native/third_party` folder in node modules.
4. Copying node modules from older system.
5. Copying `third-party` and `glog-0.3.4` from older system.
6. Deleting `test-driver` file inside `third-party` folder.
7. Unlinking `test-driver` file inside third-party folder.
8. Installing `automake-1.16` and creating a new alias of `test-driver` file inside `third-party` folder.

My java version is 1.8.0_201. My android studio version is 3.3.2. Projects react native version is 0.55.4. My mac os version is 10.14.4. My x code version is 10.2.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Unlinking as below and restart with the cache cleaned**

In project folder:

`unlink ./node_modules/react-native/scripts/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver`

and then stop js server and run:

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

It should work